# Send Github Markdown API request with urllib in python 3 got BadStatusLine

Tags: python, json, urllib, github-api

I have follow python code to convert a markdown using [github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/).

*gfm.py* (python 3 code)

```py
import traceback
import json
import urllib.request
import http.client
import sys

try:
    content = open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read()
    data = {"text": content,"mode": 'gfm'}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    bytes = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    url = "https://api.github.com/markdown"

    request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=bytes, headers=headers)
    result = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read().decode('utf-8')
    print(result)
except http.client.BadStatusLine:
    traceback.print_exc()
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Scripts and test markdown files used below are contained here: https://gist.github.com/xpol/6332952

When convert small markdown file (eg. `gfm.py Sample.md` in gist), it got fine result.

When convert large markdown file (eg. `gfm.py Cheatsheet.md` in gist), it got `http.client.BadStatusLine: ''` when at the `urllib.request.urlopen` line.

Could any one know what's wrong with this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anyone can help about this?

Comment: If you are okay with using a different library or a cli tool you can try [gifc](https://github.com/armsp/gifc) too written in Python. Or you can at least reverse engineer its source. Its just a single script.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce this but I will suggest regardless that you use a library like python-requests or even an API wrapper listed [in the GitHub API docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#python).